# Vector graphics artefacts: saving Powerpoint graphics to PDF results in blurred pixels

Tags: pdf, plot, powerpoint, vector-graphics

I have used Powerpoint 2016 to create a complex plot, based on an imported EMF graph saved from Matlab and some line drawings added in Powerpoint. I would like to save the entire contents of the Powerpoint slide as a PDF or EPS file, so as to have the figure as zoomable (as vector graphics).

Selecting the entire slide contents and right-clicking SavePictureAs only gives me EMF as the only vector graphics option, so instead I saved the entire presentation (consisting of a single slide) as a PDF. However, several parts of the image (those that were imported as a vector graphics EMF from Matlab) appear blurred in the saved PDF:
[image]

.. even though they look fine when viewed in Powerpoint:
[image]

Here is another example of a figure that looks fine in Powerpoint but blurred when saved as PDF:
[image]

[image]

I also tried some online converters to go from EMF (which Powerpoint can save into) to either PDF or EPS, but each of those produce its own type of artefact.

Can anyone suggest a solution to save this Powerpoint content into an artefact-free PDF or EPS file?

Comment: I've replied to your identical post on MS Answers' PowerPoint forum. You can follow up there, here or both. There's less random noise and fewer babbling imbecile "experts" here though. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Steve - will reply to you on the other website..

Answer (score 1):

z8080 and I have been following up on this in Microsoft Answers' PowerPoint forum, but I thought I'd come back and fill in what we've learned.

In the second example above, the grid is actually not vector graphics. It's a 7x7 pixel image. Each of the squares in the grid is actually a single pixel, blown WAY up.

Problem is, when PowerPoint prints/saves as PDF, it wants to "help" by antialiasing and upscaling the image to eliminate the jaggies. With most ordinary photos, this is usually A Good Thing.  In this case, not.

To make matters worse, the slide size of z8080's presentation is quite large, which seems to cause PPT to upscale to a much larger number of pixels than it ordinarily would.  I found that if I created a new presentation at the normal default slide size and pasted the graphic from z8080's presentation into it, the resulting PDF looked much more like the original slide, as expected.

Comment: I would add that [this](https://online2pdf.com/convert-pptx-to-pdf) converter did the job quite well, so in the present case, this is what I'll go with. Thanks again Steve for helping out!